# Crash while opening a RTMP file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I have written code to play video using ffmpeg.

The code works fine when i open AVI files but when i try to open a RTMP feed i get error.

in the utils.c file in the following function of the utils.c file

utils.c

```
int avcodec_parameters_to_context(AVCodecContext *codec,
 const AVCodecParameters *par)

{
    codec->codec_type = par->codec_type;  // crash happens at this line.


}
```

**par was nullptr

this is my code

```
 if (load_frame("rtmp://192.168.1.2/live/sumit", &file_width, &file_height, &myData)) {
        std::cout << "file Loaded";
    }
```

defination for load_frame function

```
AVFormatContext *av_format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!av_format_ctx) {
        std::cout << "could not create a format context\n";
        return false;
    }
    
    if (avformat_open_input(&av_format_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't open video file\n";
        return false;
    }
    AVCodecParameters* av_codec_params = nullptr;
    AVCodec* av_codec = nullptr;
    int video_stream_index = -1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < av_format_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        auto stream = av_format_ctx->streams[i];
        av_codec_params = av_format_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar;
        av_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(av_codec_params->codec_id);
        
        if (!av_codec) {
            std::cout << "Couldn't find the codec\n";
            continue;
        }

        if (av_codec_params->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            video_stream_index = i;
            std::cout << "Video stream found" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        if (video_stream_index < 0)
            return false;
    }

    // set up codec context for the decoder
    AVCodecContext* av_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(av_codec);
    if (!av_codec_ctx) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't create AV context";
        return false;
    }
      
   // this function invokes the error
    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(av_codec_ctx, av_codec_params) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't initialize AVCodecContext";
        return false;
    }
```

////////////////// EDIT /////////////////////////////////

I am streaming a mpeg file and av_format_ctx->nb_streams return value of 0 , why is it not able to find any streams.

i can view the same file on vlc through streaming option in vlc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of `avformat_open_input` like `fopen`. It will open a stream/file, but you still do not have an information on the stream/file contents, only a handle to do further operation with.

If you want to actually look at the data in the stream/file, you must first read the headers to determine what is inside. `avformat_find_stream_info` will accomplish that